# Что такое контекст устройства в windows-программировании?

Tags: windows

Очень часто сталкиваюсь с особенными указателями, но дальше их объявления и "слепого" использования для меня темный лес. Что это такое - контекст устройства?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все очень просто. Допустим, Вашему коду нужно где-то нарисовать. Ему нужно знать, где именно, не будет же просто на экране рисовать и угадывать координаты. Поэтому у ядра системы есть список объектов, на которых можно рисовать, у каждого есть свой уникальный идентификатор. Передав ядру этот идентификатор и действие, можно получить желаемый результат.

Вот этот указатель, он же идентификатор объекта внутри ядра, и является контекстом устройства.

Comment: т.е. это дескриптор(указатель) где то в ядре и у этого дескриптора есть набор уникальных правил(специальных функций) что нужно делать что бы с объектом произошло изменения? правильно я понял?

Comment: Это указатель, но, может, и нет. Это может быть индекс в массиве.

И да, для него скорее всего будет набор прав и функций.

Comment: Спасибо, хороший человек, все понятно.